# Hovering Bootstrap Navbar gap issue

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to have a hovering navbar, which works fine, but I want to keep in with the style of the site. The site's dropdown is 20px below the navbar, when you hover the navbar and go to travel to the dropdown it hides. It looks similar to this:

[image]

Heres and example [on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMVwGZ)

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
  /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following solution using an inner `<div>` element to push the menu items down. I also recommend to use a additional class for your customization (in this case `.custom-dropdown`) so you only change the custom dropdown and not all dropdown elements on your side.

```css
html, body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.custom-dropdown.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.custom-dropdown.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active {
  /** without this, clicking will make it sticky. */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-dropdown .dropdown-menu .inner-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu border-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <div class="inner-dropdown-menu border rounded">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you remove the `margin-top` property and make it into `padding-top:20px;`. That would eliminate the gap and make the dropdown bar more spacious. I do not know if that is what you wanted, I could not understand your question accurately

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible only with CSS. You have to write little java-script also.
You can write on focus event and change the css of dropdown menu. Then write click event out of menu element then hide. This way we can solve this issue. If you really want space between menu link and dropdown avoid using hover make it click.